# Laravel can only login in Incognito tab

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a strange issue with my Laravel project. Can't find out, when it first started - I can only login/logout opening the app in the incognito tab. And in the normal tab it won't log me out, when I am already logged in and after I deleted the session info in the storage I was unable to ever login.

I have set a `SESSION_DOMAIN` previously in the env and I faced another issue,  unable to login with Laravel Socialite on `www.*` subdomain. Later I deleted the `SESSION_DOMAIN` property, because it did not solve the issue.

After some research I found that:

The problem has occurred because I set and `SESSION_DOMAIN` in the *.env* file. When I do that during logging in on the local environment, the problem occurs even when I am in the incognito tab. Though I can remove and then reload the incognito pages again, the problem disappears for incognito tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't use Laravel, so might not fully understand how SESSION_DOMAIN should work there, but the problem seems to be due to existing a cookie set on higher domain.

For example, your code is working on domain 'sales.domain.com'. When you create a session in Laravel, it would put a cookie that's valid on that domain. It then can be removed using the same "set cookie" request but with date in the past. This is how it normally works.

But if someone (maybe your code) some time ago also set a cookie with the same name, but valid on all subdomains or '.domain.com', it can't be removed by "set cookie" request that removes it from 'sales.domain.com'.

To check this, use Firebug or Chrome dev tools to see the request header when doing request to 'sales.domain.com' and just 'domain.com'. Note the "Cookie" header. If the same cookie is present on both request, this confirms my guess. You can solve this by clearing cookies in browser.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

Comment: and is there any way to force users to clear their browser cookies?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make users clear cookies, apart from asking them to do. But if you have control over upper domain and can deploy code there, you can put logout script there and delete the cookie in it. Alternatively you can change your code or PHP configuration to use different cookie name for session (this may be specific to Laravel and as I said I don't know much about it)

Comment: Perfect, clearing all the cookies for the specific domain worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meet the problem with the subdomain cookie name. If subdomain uses same Laravel framework. Try to change Session Cookie Name in config/session.php to unique name between the main domain and the subdomain.

Comment: Actually using SESSION_DOMAIN in Laravel you need to make sure to use the same root domain (in SESSION_DOMAIN) and same APP_KEY between Laravel instances, otherwise, root cookies will cause troubles in subdomains...

Comment: I mean subdomain and the main domain should have different cookie key name, edited

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue when trying to login to my utility provider to pay by bill online. I tried everything suggested from clearing cookies to the cache and several other suggestions that either did not apply or plain did not work. It wasn't until I started trying different options within settings that I came across my resolution. I thought deleting cookies was the fix until I refreshed the page and/or logged off and tried to login again that I received the blank page with the header "THE SPECIFIED URL CAN NOT BE LOCATED" and once again only worked if I went into incognito mode.

The resolution that fixed this issue completely for me was to go into settings and turn off "DO NOT TRACK". I hope this is helpful to at least one person.
Thank You